# Probabilistically pick a candidate

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a list of candidates which looks like this:

```
candidates = [
    {
        'name': 'John',
        'rank': 13
    },
    {
        'name': 'Joe',
        'rank': 8
    },
    {
        'name': 'Averell',
        'rank': 5
    },
    {
        'name': 'William',
        'rank': 2
    }
]
```

What I want to do is semi-randomly pick one of these candidates, based on its squared rank. So that a candidate `A` having a rank twice as big as `B`, will have 4 times more chances to be picked than `B`.

Here is a naive implementation of the idea I had to solve this problem:

```
def pick_candidate(candidates):
    # initiates a global probability space
    prob_space = []

    # bring the max rank to 20
    # to avoid useless CPU burning
    # while keeping a good granularity -
    # basically, just bring the top rank to 20
    # and the rest will be divided proportionally
    rate = candidates[0]['rank'] / 20

    # fills the probability space with the indexes
    # of 'candidates', so that prob_space looks like:
    # [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
    # if candidates[0] has rank 3 and candidates[1] has rank 2
    for i, c in enumerate(candidates):
        rank = c['rank'] / rate
        for j in range(int(rank*rank)):
            prob_space.append(i)

    # picks a random index from the probability space
    picked_prob_space_index = random.randint(0, len(prob_space)-1)

    # retrieves the matching candidate
    picked_candidate_index = prob_space[picked_prob_space_index]

    return candidates[picked_candidate_index]
```

**The questions I'm thinking of, concerning the above code, are:**

- **Concept**: Is the core principle of the algorithm (the idea of building `prob_space`, etc) overkill and solvable more easily in other ways or with builtins
- **Implementation**: This core principle put aside, what do you think of the implementation? Would you think of a better, cleaner way to write it?

Answer (score 4):

### Concept

- imho you don't need build `prob_space` or normalize by max rank == 20
- you only need

  ```
  John: 1 ... 13^2
  Joe:  13^2+1 ... 13^2+8^2
  Averell: 13^2+8^2+1 ... 13^2+8^2+5^2
  William: 13^2+8^2+5^2 ... 13^2+8^2+5^2+2^2
  and choice a man having ranint(1, 13^2+8^2+5^2+2^2)
  ```
- transform list `[13**2, 8**2, 5**2, ...]` to `[13**2, 13**2+8**2, 13**2+8**2+5**2, ...]` we can by [accumulate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate)
- searching in this sorted list `[13**2, 13**2+8**2, 13**2+8**2+5**2, ...]` we can by [binary search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) implemented in [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/bisect.html) module
- the algorithm:

  ```
  from collections import namedtuple
  from itertools import accumulate
  from random import randint
  from bisect import bisect_left

  Candidate = namedtuple('Candidate', 'name rank')


  def pick_random_candidate(candidates):
      assert (len(candidates) > 0) # note: probably we want return None with empty list?
      squared_ranks_accumulated = list(accumulate(c.rank ** 2 for c in candidates))
      random_pick = randint(1, squared_ranks_accumulated[-1])
      return candidates[bisect_left(squared_ranks_accumulated, random_pick)]


  if __name__ == "__main__":
      candidates = [Candidate(*t) for t in [('John', 13), ('Joe', 8), ('Averell', 5), ('William', 2)]]
      random_candidate = pick_random_candidate(candidates)
      print(random_candidate)
  ```

### Implementation

- better use `from random import randint` instead of `import random`
- if you have `randint(0, x - 1)` you can replace it by `randrange(x)`
- constants like 20 should be defined as variable, e.g. `top_rank = 20` or even `def pick_candidate(candidates, top_rank=20)`. Reason: if someone change 20 to 21 in next three months there are high probability that don't change comment (so better when comment explains `top_rank` not `20`)
- you can often define structure Candidate as `namedtuple` (`dict` is better only sometimes if have some dynamic fields to store)
- what's with the empty list of `candidates` (exception `KeyError` is expected or something else should be?)

Comment: The concept is similar to `def grade` example at [bisect documentation module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#other-examples). The [binary search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) is very powerful when we have sorted list.

Comment: Ok, i understand now. Add explanation about accumulate and bisect* function.

Answer (score 1):

The fourth dalton is [Jack, not John](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Daltons_%28Lucky_Luke%29#William_and_Jack_Dalton).

---

You can simplify your writting a bit:

- Using `random.choice`:

  > ```python
  > picked_prob_space_index = random.randint(0, len(prob_space) - 1)
  > picked_candidate_index = prob_space[picked_prob_space_index]
  > ```

  becomes

  ```python
  picked_candidate_index = random.choice(prob_space)
  ```
- Using list-comprehension, your `for` loops becomes

  ```python
  prob_space = [i for i, candidate in enumerate(candidates) for _ in range(int((candidate['rank']/rate)**2))]
  ```

You can also improve a bit:

- By using the maximum of the ranks instead of the first one to compute the rate; this lets you *not* rely on having the maximum rank on the first candidate:

  ```python
  ranks = [c['rank'] for c in candidates]
  rate = max(ranks) / 20
  ```
- If you can change the input format and know that the informations won't change over time, you can use a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) instead of dictionaries. Modified function would look like:

  ```python
  from collections import namedtuple
  import random

  Candidate = namedtuple('Candidate', 'name rank')

  def pick_candidate(candidates):
      ranks = [c.rank for c in candidates]
      rate = max(ranks) / 20
      prob_space = [i for i, r in enumerate(ranks) for _ in range(int((r/rate)**2))]
      return candidate[random.choice(prob_space)]

  candidates = [
      Candidate('Joe', 8),
      Candidate('William', 2),
      Candidate('Jack', 13),
      Candidate('Averell', 5),
  ]
  print(pick_candidate(candidates))
  ```